# jQuery & ionic checkbox if else

Tags: android, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem I can not solve, ask for help. I am using the ionic framework and jQuery to make an insurance calculator application.

```js
var potoreg = 0;
var tabl = 0;
var potvrda = 0;
var uplate = 10;

 $(document).on('change', '#potvrda', function() { 
   if ($(this).is(' :checked')) {
   potvrda = 5;
   uplate = Number(uplate) + 1;
   }
  else {
   uplate = Number(uplate) - 1;
   potvrda = 0;
   }
  $('#uplate').val(uplate);
        $('#potvrdaovl').val(potvrda);
  get_total();
 });
 
 $(document).on('change', '#saobracajna', function() {
   if ($(this).is(' :checked')) {
   potoreg = 5;
   uplate = Number(uplate) + 1;
   }
  else {
   potoreg = 0;
   uplate = Number(uplate) - 1;
   }
  $('#uplate').val(uplate);
  $('#potvrdaoreg').val(potoreg);
  get_total();
 });

 $(document).on('change', '#tablice', function() {
   if ($(this).is(' :checked')) {
   tabl = 20;
   uplate = Number(uplate) + 1;
   }
  else {
   tabl = 0;
   uplate = Number(uplate) - 1;
   }
  $('#uplate').val(uplate);
  $('#tablice1').val(tabl);
  get_total();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item item-checkbox  checkbox-calm">
     Nova potvrda o vlasništvu?
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="potvrda">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item item-checkbox  checkbox-calm">
     Nova potvrda o registraciji?
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="saobracajna">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item item-checkbox  checkbox-calm">
     Nove registarske tablice?
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tablice">
    </label>
  </li>
```

The problem is +1 and -1, because everything is working perfectly but this is not.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks you
Can you try to over applications
[Google play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimrapro.osiguranje)

Comment: Ionic is angular based so why are you not using ng-change and ng-model on your controller?